# OpenGL: What's the point of the "named" buffer functions if you have to bind a target anyway?

Tags: c++, opengl

e.g. when I do

```cpp
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _id);
glNamedBufferData(_id, size, data, static_cast<GLenum>(usage));
```

then program works as expected. But if I delete that first line, my program crashes and prints:

> ERROR 1282 in glNamedBufferData

Likewise, if I do

```cpp
glBindVertexArray(_id);

GLuint attribIndex = 0;
GLuint offset = 0;
for(const GlslType type : layout) {
    const auto& attrib = GLSL_TYPES.at(type);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(_id, attribIndex, attrib.size, static_cast<GLenum>(attrib.type), GL_FALSE, offset);
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(_id, attribIndex);
    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(_id, attribIndex, 0);
    offset += attrib.size_bytes();
}
```

It works fine, but if I delete the `glBindVertexArray` then it doesn't work and prints:

> ERROR 1282 in glVertexArrayAttribFormat
> ERROR 1282 in glEnableVertexArrayAttrib
> ERROR 1282 in glVertexArrayAttribBinding

I figured that by "naming" the VBO or VAO when calling those functions then I wouldn't have to bind it beforehand. But if I have to bind regardless, what's the benefit of these functions that require the extra name argument?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `glGen*` functions create a integer name representing an object, but they don't create the object state itself (well, most of them don't). It is only when you bind those objects do they gain their state, and only after they have state can any function be called which requires them to have state. In particular, the [direct state access functions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Direct_State_Access).

This is why [`ARB_direct_state_access`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_direct_state_access.txt) *also* includes the `glCreate*` functions. These functions create an integer name *and* the state data for objects. Therefore, you don't have to bind anything to manipulate direct state access functions, so long as you properly created the object beforehand.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense! Also explains why it says "If no buffer object with name buffer exists, one is created with that name" in the glBindBuffer docs; I don't think that was super relevant before DSA because you had to bind regardless.